# Pass Javascript variable to URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a bunch of URL's that automatically load images on a webpage I am developing:

```
<a href="https://www.sample1.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://www.sample1.com" alt="sample1"
<a href="https://www.sample2.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://www.sample2.com" alt="sample2">

...
```

However, some of the images that I need displayed are dynamic and are based on the current time. I know how to get the proper time, hour, and hour in UTC, and then properly define the variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
var datee = new Date()
var yyyy = datee.getFullYear()
var mm = datee.getMonth() + 1
var dd = datee.getDate()
var mms = datee.getMinutes()
var hh_UTC = datee.getUTCHours()
var outlook_hour = []   

if (parseInt(hh_UTC) > 0 && parseInt(hh_UTC) < 12){outlook_hour = "0100"}
if (parseInt(hh_UTC) > 11 && parseInt(hh_UTC) < 13){outlook_hour = "1200"}
if (parseInt(hh_UTC) > 13 && parseInt(hh_UTC) < 17){outlook_hour = "1630"}
if (parseInt(hh_UTC) > 16 && parseInt(hh_UTC) < 21){outlook_hour = "2000"}
    
var url1 = "https://sample_img_" + outlook_hour + ".gif"
    
</script>
```

How am I able to extract the 'url1' variable to have the image load on my page in similar fashion to the first block of code provided? All I could find while searching online is the 'document.getElementbyID' in which I don't really have an 'ID'. Therefore, something along the lines of:

```
<a href="https://www.updated_img.com" target="_blank">
  <img src=document.getElementbyID(url1) alt="sample_img">
```

would not work. Therefore, how would I be able to pass the 'url1' variable in the above piece of code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to give your image an id, and then set the `src` attribute of it to the value of the variable:

**HTML:**

```html
<a href="https://www.updated_img.com" target="_blank">
<img id="image1" alt="sample_img">
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {// wait until the page is fully loaded before interacting with the document
  document.getElementById("image1").setAttribute("src", url1);
})
```